# Countdown timer SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to make a countdown timer daily at a specific time. When I open the application again, the timer is reset and the countdown starts again, I'm trying to figure out how to make the timer start again after its time has elapsed..

For example, so that this timer starts over every day at 6 pm

```
struct TimerView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @State var timeRemaining = 24*60*60
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("\(timeString(time: timeRemaining))")
            .font(.system(size: 60))
            .frame(height: 80.0)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.black)
            .onReceive(timer){ _ in
                if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                    self.timeRemaining -= 1
                }else{
                    self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                }
            }
    }
    
    //Convert the time into 24hr (24:00:00) format
    func timeString(time: Int) -> String {
        let hours   = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the timer is reset and the countdown starts again

You could try to play with UserDefaults to store variables in the device's memory.

Here is the Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: But how to update the timer at a certain time? for example at 6 pm, because with `UserDefaults` the countdown will start from the time the user opened the application, and not from a specific time

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TimelineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview) and [AppStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage) e.g.

```
@AppStorage("StartDate") var startDate: Date
...
TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 1)) { context in
    AnalogTimerView(date: context.date)
}
```

Comment: I'm new and I don't really understand how to combine this with my code

Comment: Can you help me with my code example? @malhal

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you want to achieve. E.g. do you want to countdown until a certain time? Or do you want to start a countdown timer from a certain time? Some more detail in your question would help.

Comment: start a countdown timer from a certain time , for example, so that this timer starts every day at 6 pm